# Curl doesn't recognize the url

Tags: curl

I am trying to execute the following command and receive the error

```
curl.exe -X POST --request "http://localhost:5000/text/analytics/v3.0-preview/sentiment" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"documents\":[{\"language\":\"en\",\"id\":\"1-en\",\"text\":\"Hello world. This is some input text that I love.\"}]}"  -g

curl: (3) Port number ended with '['
```

or MissingRequiredBody because for some reason it sees my data as endpoint :/ I must be doing something obviously wrong, so apologies in advance if the question is trivial

The things I tried so far:

1. verified the url. It is correct, it returns response to GET calls
2. verified the body with JSON formatter
3. tested the call with Swagger (on the same machine as I am trying to execute the command). It was successful
   [image]
4. --data-raw, --data-binary
5. added --request. No difference
6. removed POST. No difference
7. started the body with single inverted comma and removed / escape
8. saved the body in a variable and used the variable
9. played with -g globbing flag. No difference
10. restarted the session. No difference

[image]

Comment: PowerShell is garbage and have [insane quote rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/twistylittlepassagesallalike/everyone-quotes-command-line-arguments-the-wrong-way) which you are violating somehow. switch to Cygwin or WSL or something, Linux shells have trivial escape rules: strings start-and-ends with `'` and every `'` needs to be escaped as `'\''`, that's it. the only other rule is that null-bytes aren't allowed. Windows shell escape rules OTOH is friggin black magic (and you're escaping it wrong here, somehow, but idk how)

Comment: I am a big fan of Powershell, so please do not trash talk it :)
But yes, you were right, WSL was the solution. Can you please add it as an answer, so that I can accept it?
Thank you for the help!